# Can't achieve http request parallelism

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, dom-events, node-modules

I have an application written in Node that sends Http requests in a loop towards one web server and logs how much requests it receives every 1 second. My problem is that I only receive maximum of 10 requests per second which is absolutely low taking the fact I have 2<sup>16</sup> ports available and big upload/download speed. When I use some other low level languages that support multi-threading such as Java I manage to get around 600-700 requests per second which is far more then this number. My code is very trivial and only thing I do is do an infinite loop and send requests towards web server and in response, increment an global variable which I print every 1 second to understand how much requests came back.

```
async function sendTestRequest() {
    var uUrl = 'https://sometestwebserver.io/';

    axios.get(uUrl, {
        jar: cookieJar, // tough.CookieJar or boolean
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
            'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'
        },
        withCredentials: true
    }).then(response => {
        bmak.globalCnt++;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
};

async function main() {
    bmak.globalCnt = 0;
    var currDate = Date.now();
    for (let w = 0; 1 == 1; w++) {
            sendTestRequest()
            if (Date.now() - currDate >= 1000) {
                console.log("Received requests: " + bmak.globalCnt);
                currDate = Date.now();
            }
            continue;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet it's because your `main()` is starving the event loop.  It synchronously calls `sendTestRequest` infinitely, never yielding control of the JavaScript thread for I/O to process.

I'd rework this to have a maximum concurrency.  `main()` should call `sendTestRequest()` that number of times, and then when your HTTP request completes (ie in the `then`/`catch` callbacks), call `sendTestRequest` again.

You can then experiment a little to find a concurrency number that gets you the best performance.

PS: The `async`s used in this example are totally unnecessary since you're not actually `await`ing any promises.  You should not use `async` unless you actually need it, since it does add runtime overhead.